# Не могу найти базу данных Informix

Tags: база-данных

Существует ли сейчас СУБД Informix? Поддерживается ли сейчас она? Если существует, помогите найти ссылку на скачивание и как там создать базу данных?

Нашел только Server Instance Manager.

Answer (score 0):

СУБД Informix была первоначально разработана Informix Corporation, дочерняя компания Informix Software была приобретена IBM в 2001 году. Выпуск новых версий СУБД и их текущая поддержка продолжается под брендом IBM Informix. Демонстрационную версию СУБД можно скачать здесь: https://www.ibm.com/products/informix. Обзор (ретроспективный) линейки продуктов IBM Informix почитать на русском языке - здесь: https://ru.bmstu.wiki/IBM_Informix.